# Calling a stored procedure via PHP in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, stored-procedures, php-mongodb

Dear everybody who can help,

I have this PHP > MongoDB problem, I want to call a stored procedure (stored in db.system.js collection) via PHP.

I have no parameters, only a returning JSON object which looks like this:

```
{"archived":[the number of the archived messages]}
```

It works good in the shell on the database server, but when I try to call it via the PHP driver it just doesn't "say" anything...

My code looks like this:

```
$DB->execute(
    new MongoCode(
        "function () { return archiveMessages(); }"
    )
);
```

I have also tried to use somehow like this:

```
$DB->execute("archiveMessages()");
```

Please help, I've got stuck on this one... I only want to call that sh*t after updating the  collection...

Thank you in advance,
B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the same database?  Try simplifying it to a basic example, e.g.,

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->foo;

$db->system->js->save(array("_id"=>"archiveMessages", 
   "value"=>new MongoCode("function() { return 3; }")));

print_r($db->execute("archiveMessages()"));
```

Results in:

```
Array
(   
    [retval] => 3
    [ok] => 1
)
```

Comment: I am using the same DB, it's a constant. Just like almost anything else.
This is the only thing I can't do now.

Comment: Can you print_r the result you're getting?  [retval] => null?

Comment: I get an "Error 500: Internal Server Error". My PHP driver seems to work okay, does everything I ask from it.

Comment: That's from your app server, not MongoDB.  Can you write a test script and just run it through PHP cli?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

Are you assigning the return value of execute() to a variable?

Comment: Yes, I have been even checking the returning values... I needed that number I have mentioned above for displaying...