# MongoDB PHP Driver: Using Execute for Stored JS

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I created a Stored JS function which supposedly completes a very tedious job, faster and efficiently. Now after a investing long working hours I came up with completing this functionality.

So my function is suppose myFunc();

```
db.system.js.save(
{
 _id : "myFunc" ,
 value : function (param1,param2,param3....){ ... }});
```

Once I was through with completing this function, and testing it with Mongo Shell as

```
db.eval("myFunc('a','b'...)");
```

and

```
db.loadServerScripts();
myFunc('a','b',..);
```

I was satisfied it will work,
Now the problem begins, How to achieve this with PHP?

```
$cmd = 'db.eval("myFunc(\'a\',\'b\'...);");';
$data = $mongo_db->execute($cmd);
var_dump($data);
```

$data comes up with nothing..!!

```
array(2) { ["retval"]=> NULL ["ok"]=> float(1) }
```

Somebody tell me please what the heck am I doing wrong..!!

Comment: Please provide a full example that can be copied and pasted. Having ... is not very useful.

Comment: Weel the code is about 50 loc. And I it makes 2 queries in it. But issue is resolved by a workaround. :) Still Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple workaround I found:

```
var out = db.eval("abc(param1,param2..)"); return(JSON.stringify(out));
```

I know its not at all advisable way to achieve this, but till the time I find a better workaround( as Stored JS is not an advisable method ) its the only way I have. Will post in case of any failure.

Answer (score 2):

You have a similar question at: [Calling a stored procedure via PHP in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716648/calling-a-stored-procedure-via-php-in-mongodb)

Anyway as [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) says:

> Note We do not recommend using server-side stored functions if
>   possible.

Is a better practice execute directly the JS with [MongoDB::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) instead of store it in the db.system.js and after call it:

```
$func = 
    "function(greeting, name) { ".
        "return greeting+', '+name+', says '+greeter;".
    "}";
$scope = array("greeter" => "Fred");

$code = new MongoCode($func, $scope);

$response = $db->execute($code, array("Goodbye", "Joe"));
echo $response['retval'];
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

With the MongoCode object you can use scoping and create PHP objects with you JS, and you can have this JS on your PHP project at the vcs, all together.

Comment: ?¿ Then how you make MapReduce without JS? You must have caution but about the load on the server, but you MUST use JS if you work with MongoDB.

Comment: Map reduce is not JS in the sense of this, MR runs completely differently, for one it is a database command that accepts JS callbacks

Comment: So, I understand it is not advised to use JS stored function, but I have a strong server to support my needs, and moreover I am trying to avoid calculations at my requesting server. And also using no lock for eval.